# Hide or inactivate team project in Team Explorer

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

I have one project collection and several team projects underneath.  One of the team projects is for a now redundant project and I want to hide this or inactivate it so it no longer shows up in the list of available team projects in the collection.  Is there a way of achieving this without deleting the team project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to remove everyone from security groups of this project. If people don't have access to it, they will not see it. 
I think collection administrator will always see all the projects.

Comment: Excellent, works great.  I'm collection admin and therefore it was still showing for me, but other users can no longer see it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the code you no longer needed into an "Archive" project, and make it read only.

You can then delete the Team project by doing the following.

Go to the Visual Studio command prompt and use TfsDeleteProject.exe

TfsDeleteProject / server:myserver "Project Name"

Hope this helps!

Comment: NO. By doing this way you would destroy all history when you delete the project. There is a /keephistory switch but I haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please know that when deleting projects in TFS all source-code history also ends so if you have branched code from one project to another and then deletes the first project all history will be erased from the day you branched.

It would therefore be great to have a "hide" option or "delete project but keep source history" option.